# Manage position in SQL server to handle change on front

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am developing a CMS using React in front, .NET core in the back, and SQL for the database. I want to manage the position of some elements, for example, the pages of the navbar, the categories, the products, etc.

I add a column "position" for these entities, but I don't know how to implement the process of changing positions. For example, if I have the following list:

1. Product A
2. Product B
3. Product C
4. Product D

In the database, the products are stored as follows:

```
Name            Position
Product A          0
Product B          1
Product C          2
Product D          3
```

Then if the customer moves Product A to the bottom of the list, the table in the database should be as follows:

```
Name            Position
Product A          3
Product B          0
Product C          1
Product D          2
```

I hope someone can help me with advice on how to cover this implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could have the new positions in a temp table or a CTE, you may update your original table as the following:

```
with new_positions as
(
  select 'Product A' as name, 3 as position union all
  select 'Product B', 0 union all
  select 'Product C', 1 union all
  select 'Product D', 2
)
update t
set t.Position = NP.position
from
tbl_name t join new_positions NP
on t.name = NP.name
where t.Position <> NP.Position
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/NhFh11rG)